# WCF Thread was being aborted error

Tags: wcf, iis

I have a WCF service that works fine in IIS 7, however once deployed to Windows Server 2003, IIS6, I'm now getting - "The thread was being aborted" error message. This happens after a few minutes of the service running.

I've tried manually changing some timeout values and turned off IIS keep alives.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem would be welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: I've realized this has nothing to do with timeout values in my case, but there must be some offending code I am trying to track down, will post my answer once I've determined the exact cause.

Comment: You wouldn't have happened to figure out what happened would you?  I think we're running into the same problem here.

Comment: @Kevin, I would recommend switching back to asmx, or upgrading to framework 4.0 (because I have heard that WCF has some improvements, but no personal experience with this). My solution was to downgrade to asmx, which throws real errors that are easier to debug and solve.

Comment: I had the same situation but I found the solution on the internet. I used respons.redirect within the try catch block. Once I removed and put outside the try catch then it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having this problem - please read! Hopefully you'll save yourself A LOT of trouble knowing this. Get coffee first!

You might come from a traditional programming background, in fields not SOA related, and now you're writing SOA services with the mindset of "traditional programmer". Here are 4 of the most important lessons I've learnt since building SOA services.

**Rule number 1**

Try your very best not to write services that take an extended amount of time to complete. I know this can be VERY tricky to accomplish, but it is much more reliable to have smaller operations being called many times, than 1 long service performing all the work, then returning a response. For example recently I wrote a service which processed ALL tasks. Each task was stored as an XML file in the IIS site, and each task would export data to a system for example : SharePoint. At any given times during high volumes there could be up to 30 000 tasks waiting to be processed. Over the past 2 months I have yet to get it 100% reliable, this is after diving deep into timeout settings in IIS, AppPools and WCF bindings. Every now and again I would get - "The thread was being aborted" and no reason or explanation as to why this was happening. I exhausted all online knowledge bases, no one seemed the wiser. Eventually after not being able to fix the issues or even reproduce them in a reliable way, I opted for a complete rewrite. I changed my code to instead of process ALL tasks, process just 1 task at a time.

This essentially meant calling 1 web service 30 000 times, rather than calling it once, but performance wise, it is around the same. Each call issues a response quick, and does a lot less work. This has another benefit, I can provide instant feedback on each operation to the client. In the Long call, you get a response back right at the end and ALL at once.

You can also much more easily catch and retry a service call if it does fail, because you don't have to redo the whole call for each operation again, but simply the operation that failed.

Its easier to test too, not only because of the live feedback, but also because you can test 1 inner operation, without the overhead of the loop if you wanted to.

Lastly it adds better scaling if you plan on extending your application later, because you're broken things down into more manageable units of work. So for example: Before you had 1 service which processed ALL Tasks, now you have a web service that can process 1 TASK, because of this you can more easily extend the functionality if you needed to process 10 Tasks, or tasks by selection.

**Rule Number 2**
Don't upgrade your existing ASMX web services to WCF 3 just because you think its a better technology. WCF 3 is over architectured and not a real pleasure to work with, or deploy. If you need to go WCF, try your best to hold out for the version that ships with .net 4 of the framework, it seems to have been revamped. Another thing you will miss is that WCF has no test forms, so you can't just fire up a web browser quick to test your services. If you're like me - "Keep it simple stupid" Then WCF 3.5 will frustrate you.

**Rule Number 3**
IIS6 can be dodgy, if at all possible avoid having to host your services in IIS6, if you're after reliable services. I am not saying its impossible to achieve reliability in IIS6, but it requires a LOT of work, and a great deal of testing. If you're dealing with services that are critical, try avoid using a product developed in 2001.

**Rule Number 4**
Don't underestimate the development and testing required to create reliable SOA services. To be honest all I can say is it is a massive undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd mention that this error is thrown by SharePoint when calling some functions from a user account.  Those functions need to be run with `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`

This answer shows up when searching for "wcf sharepoint Thread was being aborted" so hopefully this can be useful to someone since 'thread being aborted' isn't very useful of SharePoint to throw when its a permissions issue.